# Free abelian group on a space and fibrations

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, principal-bundles, fibration

Let $X$ be a topological space. Endow the free abelian group on $X$, $\mathbb Z[X]$, the quotient topology coming from the surjection $\bigsqcup_n X^n \times \mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb Z[X]$. For $Y$ a sub-CW-complex of a CW-complex $X$, the quotient map $\mathbb Z[X] \to \mathbb Z[X]/\mathbb Z[Y]$ is a quasi-fibration (see e.g. Salvatore Lemma 6.1 https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9907073.pdf). Is this quotient map a Serre fibration?